# How to merge two Regions in EyeShot?

Tags: c#, eyeshot

I'm working on a program where I need to merge two `devDept.Eyeshot.Entities.Region`s.

Is there a method or function built in `EyeShot` to do this automatically, or should I do it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean Union? You can do boolean operations between *Region* entities using:

```
Region[] result = devDept.Eyeshot.Region.Union(r1, r2);
```